# How to JOIN 2 MySQL tables to determine if joined table has a match

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 MySQL tables (countries) and (reservations)

I want to list every row from `countries` and simply indicate whether there is a match on `reservations` or not.

In each instance:

- `reservations` will have 1 matching rows, or
- `reservations` will have many matching rows, or
- `reservations` will have no matching rows

So all I want from the join is to know whether there is a match to `reservations` or not. Nothing else.

Here is my query statement:

```
SELECT country.countryID, reservation.citizen
FROM countries AS country
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT reservationID
  FROM reservations
  LIMIT 1
) AS reservation ON reservation.citizen = country.countryID
ORDER BY reservation.citizen
```

It fails with **Unknown column 'reservation.citizen' in 'on clause'**

CONCLUSION:
JOINs cannot solve the problem.

Comment: In `FROM reservations` you say the table name is `reservations`, but elsewhere you say the name is `reservation`. I think you would need to fix this before you can identify further issues.

Comment: Doesn't the `AS reservation` handle that @user151841 ?

Comment: oh, you're right : P

Comment: Okay -- this would be the problem, then -- `SELECT reservationID
  FROM reservations
  LIMIT 1` would only return one result of one column, called `reservationID`. That's why it's saying it can't find the column `reservation.citizen`. You need also to `SELECT reservationID, citizen ...`

Comment: Ok, close @user151841 .. thanks. Got the script to not fail, but it does not return any value from the `reservations` table which I know it should

Comment: As a test, try running your subquery alone: `SELECT reservationID
  FROM reservations
  LIMIT 1`. If it doesn't return what you want, then it's probably causing the entire query to return results you don't want either.

Comment: Well, I have looked into the raw tables and I know what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the subselect. Notice you have not included the field citizen inside reservation.

```
SELECT country.countryID, reservation.citizen
FROM countries AS country
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT reservationID, citizen
  FROM reservations
  LIMIT 1
) AS reservation ON reservation.citizen = country.countryID
ORDER BY reservation.citizen
```

By the other hand, why are you doing a subselect? And why the limit? Wouldn't be better to just query the following?

```
SELECT 
    country.countryID, 
    count(reservation.reservationID)
FROM 
    countries AS country
    LEFT JOIN reservations AS reservation 
    ON country.countryID = reservation.citizen
GROUP BY
    country.countryID
HAVING 
    count(reservation.reservationID) > 0
ORDER BY 
    reservation.citizen
;
```

Comment: Well, that does not quite work. 1st I needed to remove the comma separator between GROUP BY and HAVING to get past the error message. Next the script runs forever as there are 245 country records and over 95,000 reservation record. (I am trying to use a MySQL query statement to simply this. I can easily run a 2nd MySQL query inline with my PHP to do a lookup, but I was trying to make this more compact.) Lastly, I need all 245 country rows to return -- hence the reason for LEFT JOIN. But this solution only returned 79 rows so the countries with no reservations are being left off the result list

Comment: If you want all countries to be returned just remove the having

Comment: Another solution would be to make to COUNT in the subselect and join it afterwards

Comment: Perfect, it works @user3159821. Only problem is the script runs a long time and would not be used. It does accurately count the number of matching rows, but all I wanted to know is a "yah" or "nay" -- hence my attempt with LIMIT 1 in order to speed up the process. Looks like JOINS cannot solve this problem so an inline subsequent lookup is the way to go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the relation between reservations and countries is 1to1, you could first make a  distinct or a group by in RESERVATION by CITIZEN and a FULL OUTER JOIN with country table. SELECT
 country.countryID
 reservation.has_reservation
FROM
 countries as country
 FULL OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT DISTINCT
  citizen,
  1 as has_reservation
 FROM
  reservations
 ) as reservation
 ON country.countryID = reservation.citizen
; Performance in GROUP BY will be a problem.

Comment: countries has 245 static rows. reservations has 95,000 rows and growing. relations ship is one-to-many. I wonder if `indexing` can speed up the process?

Comment: Wow, I just put an index on the reservations table and it flies.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with the join, it should be like

```
LEFT JOIN reservations AS reservation ON reservation.citizen = country.countryID
ORDER BY reservation.citizen
```

OR

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM reservations
  LIMIT 1
) AS reservation ON reservation.citizen = country.countryID
 ORDER BY reservation.citizen
```

OR better LEFT OUTER JOIN to get rows not matching join conditions.

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations AS reservation ON reservation.citizen = country.countryID
ORDER BY reservation.citizen
```

Comment: It runs fine except the JOIN returns no results -- I know it should

Comment: Nah, the LEFT OUTER JOIN (a) causes the script to run a long time and (b) returned close to 4,000 rows. There only should be 246 rows returned

Comment: It appears that my objective is not solvable using JOINs